# Collapsing dataframe in R without summation

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```r
df <- data.frame(id= c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2), error_1 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0), error_2 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0), error_3 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1))

> df
  id error_1 error_2 error_3
1  1       0       1       1
2  1       0       0       0
3  2       0       0       0
4  1       1       0       1
5  2       0       0       1
```

I would like to "collapse" it in a way such that records with the same ID will be joined into a single row that displays with a "1" whether or not an error of that specific type occurred (rather than the number of times it did so):

```
> df_result
  id error_1 error_2 error_3
  1       1       1       1
  2       0       0       1
```

What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df |>
  summarize(across(everything(), max), .by = id)

  id error_1 error_2 error_3
1  1       1       1       1
2  2       0       0       1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick to vanilla R (without Tidyverse), you can use the [`aggregate` function](https://rdrr.io/r/stats/aggregate.html) to group the rows by the `id` column and the reduce each column in each group with an arbitrary function.

In this case, if you know that the `error_*` columns will always be binary (either 0 or 1), you can use the `max` function as a reducer:

```r
aggregate(df, . ~ id, max)
#   id error_1 error_2 error_3
# 1  1       1       1       1
# 2  2       0       0       1
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively please try the below code

```r
df %>% mutate(across(starts_with('error'), ~ na_if(.x,0))) %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(id) %>% fill(starts_with('error')) %>% slice_tail(n=1) %>% ungroup()



# A tibble: 2 × 4
     id error_1 error_2 error_3
  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1       1       1       1
2     2      NA      NA       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach using `any`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  summarise(across(, ~ any(. == 1)*1), .by = id)

  id error_1 error_2 error_3
1  1       1       1       1
2  2       0       0       1
```